# Count elements occur in Array Two dimension Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, count, element

Hello everybody, now i'm doing a research and i need to count "Achieved" "Unachieved" and "On-going" occur. I need to count it because my research is about Markov Decision Process and i need to define path. so, i need to count the result of each task to each P1 or P2 about Achieved , unachieved and On-going

> My file is like that :

```
a->P1-> Interrupted 
a->P1-> Achieved
a->P1-> Achieved
a->P1-> Achieved
a->P1-> Achieved
a->P1-> Achieved
a->P1-> Achieved
a->P1-> Achieved
a->P1-> On-going
a->P1-> Interrupted
a->P2-> Interrupted
a->P2-> Achieved
a->P2-> Achieved
a->P2-> Achieved
a->P2-> Achieved
a->P2-> Achieved
a->P2-> Achieved
a->P2-> Achieved
a->P2-> Achieved
a->P2-> On-going
b->P1-> Achieved
b->P1-> Achieved
b->P1-> Achieved
b->P1-> Achieved
b->P1-> Achieved
b->P1-> Achieved
b->P1-> Achieved
b->P1-> On-going
b->P1-> Interrupted
b->P2-> Interrupted
b->P2-> Achieved
b->P2-> Achieved
b->P2-> Achieved
b->P2-> Achieved
b->P2-> Achieved
b->P2-> Achieved
b->P2-> Achieved
b->P2-> Achieved
b->P2-> On-going
```

> and i want result :

```
a->P1-> achieve 7 times
a->P1-> Unachieved 2 times
a->P1-> On-going 1 time
a->P2-> achieve 8 times
........
........
```

thank you !! :)

Comment: Did you try anything? Post it.

Comment: i try doing it since the beginning that there has lots of data. i subtracted them and insert to a file and file is as i post. i'm stuck. sorry buddy.

Comment: Does the new edited response does what you want?

Comment: Sorry buddy, it's not what i want, i thank you !!! :) will find other method to solve it !! :)

Comment: It does exactly the output you are looking for though. What's missing?

Answer (score -1):

Using Java 8 Streams feature you can do it as follows:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> byType =
            Files.lines(Paths.get("c:\\Temp\\markov.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset()).
                    collect(
                            Collectors.groupingBy(String::toString));

    byType.entrySet().stream().forEach(t -> System.out.println(t.getKey() + ":" + t.getValue().size()));
```

See the following output:

```
a->P2-> Interrupted:1
a->P1-> Achieved:7
b->P1-> Interrupted:1
b->P2-> On-going:1
a->P1-> On-going:1
b->P1-> On-going:1
a->P2-> On-going:1
b->P2-> Interrupted:1
a->P1-> Interrupted:1
b->P2-> Achieved:8
b->P1-> Achieved:7
a->P2-> Achieved:8
```